# Testing modular AngularJS w/ Jasmine & Karma

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Struggling to get unit testing set up in Jasmine/Karma. I have a controller with a service dependency, and that service has another service dependency. I am not organizing my modules by type (Directives, Services, etc), but rather by feature (layout, summaryView, etc).

Here's the architecture:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'myApp.base', 'myApp.layout','myApp.common']);
angular.module('myApp.base', ['myApp.common']);
angular.module('myApp.common',[]);
angular.module('myApp.layout',['myApp.common']);
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.layout')
    .controller('LayoutCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'layoutService', 'urlService', 'BaseService',
        function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, layoutService, urlService, BaseService) {
            //controller code here
    });
```

Layout Service:

```
 angular.module('myApp.layout')
    .service('layoutService', ['$http', '$resource', '$rootScope', '$location', '$route', 'errorHandlingService', 'utilService',
        function ($http, $resource, $rootScope, $location, $route, errorHandlingService, utilService) {
            //service code here
    });
```

From what I understand, if I simply include `beforeEach(module('myApp.layout'));`, I should have access to my controllers, services, filters, and directives in my layout module.

Instead, the following code fails:

```
describe('Layout Controller', function() {
  var ctrl, scope, service;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(module('myApp.layout'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, layoutService) {

      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      service = layoutService;
      //Create the controller with the new scope
      ctrl = $controller('LayoutCtrl', {$scope: scope, layoutService: service});
      dump(scope);
    }));
    it('should exist', function() {
        expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

With this error:

```
Chrome 26.0 (Mac) Layout Controller should exist FAILED
    Error: Unknown provider: layoutServiceProvider <- layoutService
        at Error (<anonymous>)
        at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js:28:236
        at Object.c [as get] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js:26:13)
        at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js:28:317
        at c (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js:26:13)
        at Object.d [as invoke] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js:26:147)
        at workFn (http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.4/angular-mocks.js:1754:20)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.jasmine.window.inject.angular.mock.inject (http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.4/angular-mocks.js:1740:25)
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/scottsilvi/svn/BARO/web/src/test/js/unit/myApp.layoutModule.js:6:14)
        at /Users/scottsilvi/svn/BARO/web/src/test/js/unit/myApp.layoutModule.js:1:1
    Expected undefined to be defined.
    Error: Expected undefined to be defined.
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/scottsilvi/svn/BARO/web/src/test/js/unit/myApp.layoutModule.js:15:16)
Chrome 26.0 (Mac): Executed 10 of 10 (1 FAILED) (0.36 secs / 0.014 secs)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that all files are being loaded and are being loaded in the correct order?

Comment: yeah that turned out to be the issue. Some of the dependencies in myApp module weren't being loaded. As soon as I loaded them all, the tests started working. Go ahead and file an answer and I'll mark as correct. Thx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Often a Unknown Provider error comes from files not being loaded, or being loaded in the incorrect order. Check which files are present while your tests are running.

Comment: @Jmr how do you detect which files are present when tests are running?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Run karma with logLevel DEBUG

Answer (score 1):

Such kind of errors mostly occur due to incorrect declaration of files inside *karma.config.js* file. For setup of *karma-jasmine* all the files inside `file:[]` block of *karma.config.js* file should be in sequence in which they are expected to get loaded. Main module is having dependency injection of any custom service then load that service first and then main module.